# Unable to Synchronize raspberry pi node my private network

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, synchronization, iot

I have created a private network with 3 nodes - two nodes in computer and one in raspberry pi

I connected computer and raspberry pi to same network through LAN

computer ip: 192.168.122.1

pi ip address: 10.1.200.157

enode of node1: "enode://f44eea7f09627b885f012ea3947dd676f01b13bb92a18216c497ec7cccce28d958b4fb9f9c942b5d41f8169cae5e6919350a95feb2b8a4f2e022a20801be282b@192.168.122.1:30303"

enode of node2:

"enode://b00916eb3723de7e2c2ad683283b184fe639c41e902316dbca8a457f353694e02f98e1b770ae2e1e7f6216a7332087fb2701a91d20d82758e8b74651754f4bb3@192.168.122.1:30304"

enode of pi node:
"enode://090c17aac6f826e5e771c925e36933407a799747bbe31856ea69fa11e9b906e4a24a28280a28dcfc9f0bb7960083f211759b5e4cebf4b4d66d8b79358b1fac3c@10.1.200.157:30305"

Iam able to synchronize the node1 and node2 and send some ether from node1 to node2 and viceversa.

But unable to sync pi node to node1 or node2 and unable to sync node1 or node2 to pi

when i give the following command in node1 console
admin.addPeer("enode://090c17aac6f826e5e771c925e36933407a799747bbe31856ea69fa11e9b906e4a24a28280a28dcfc9f0bb7960083f211759b5e4cebf4b4d66d8b79358b1fac3c@10.1.200.157:30305")

im getting True response but when i check admin.peers i can see only node2 synced.

[image]
same if i do in node 2 console i.e. i can see only node1 sync to node1

Comment: The pi has an IP from a different network 10.1.200.xx than from your other nodes 192.168.122.yy. Perhaps there's a NAT router between them. It is likely that the nodes cannot connect between them.

Comment: Im sorry. the computer ip address is 10.1.200.48 and pi ip address is 10.1.200.157

Comment: Are your nodes running in a VM? Their ip addresses seem to be from a private lan, you need them to have an IP in your lan ie 10.1.200.xx. I think you can control that in your VM if you choose "Bridged" as network.